# How was this summation simplified to 1/i?

Tags: summation

How is the summation below simplified?

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^{2i} \frac1{i^2} = \frac{i}{i^2} = \frac1{i}$$

Thanks!

Comment: One hopes that this was encountered in a more rich context! Taken alone, this notation is *correct*, but likely to confuse anyone who encounters it. (Which is to say: don't repeat this in your own writing unless you are making a point in text about the summed term being constant *and* have a compelling reason to use the variable $i$, which is traditionally used as an index, as that constant)

Comment: Haha. This was a small part of a question for my stochastic probability class!

Comment: "stochastic probability" sounds redundant :)

Comment: oops... I mean stochastic processes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The summation variable is $j$, not $i$, so you can pull $\frac{1}{i^2}$ outside of the summation giving

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^{2i} \frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{1}{i^2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{2i}1 = \frac{1}{i^2} i = \frac{1}{i}.$$